# Main library(scipy) not getting inherited in virtual env

Tags: python, gcc, scipy, virtualenv, homebrew

I had been trying to install the libraries I generally use in Python to a new laptop. I am using mac OS Version 10.9.3 and Python 2.7 .

I installed Xcode, Homebrew.Somehow from the start Homebrew is showing error.. Generally i go by installing ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)" . This dint work . But found an alternative and now i have gcc installed.I have gcc and gfortan installed in my usr/local/bin..**which means i have gcc fortan in place for scipy.**

```
**Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> importscipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'importscipy' is not defined
>>> import scipy
>>> exit()
datlma:~ mkamalakshan$ cd Documents/DataScience/Projects/
datlma:Projects m$ workon Test
(Test)datlmeenuka:Projects mkamalakshan$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy**
>>> exit()
(Test)datlmeenuka:Projects mkamalakshan$ pip freeze
numpy==1.8.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
(Test)datlmeenuka:Projects mkamalakshan$ pip install scipy
Downloading/unpacking scipy
  Downloading scipy-0.14.0.tar.gz (10.2MB): 10.2MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/Users/mkamalakshan/.virtualenvs/Test/build/scipy/setup.py)        
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 customize PGroupFCompiler
Could not locate executable pgfortran
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
building 'dfftpack' library
error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

Can you guys please let me know what am I doing wrong ? May be i am overlooking something . or may be there are alternative workarounds.

Cheers
Meenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I found was to install macport and start over.. It really worked as a temporary solution. But I did not try virtualenvs in that . But using macport i have all scientific packages I wanted to use.

Hope this helps